# Error Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL

Tags: controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 2 Controllers

//localhost:/propertysearch

```
 [Route("property-search")]
 public ActionResult Index()
{
..
}
```

//localhost:/somesearchname

```
[Route("{searchName}")]
public ActionResult Preview(string searchName)
{
..
}
```

I tried like this, i got error like `Multiple controller types were found that match the URL`. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL.

If i want to use same route in multiple controllers how can i write?

Answer (score 2):

Add route constrain to `Preview` action that do not accept `property-search`.

```
[Route("{searchName:regex(^(?!property-search$))}")]
public ActionResult Preview(string searchName)
{
..
}
```